# Retirar valores das barras do gráfico

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Preciso tirar os números das barras do gráfico que estou usando, mas até o momento não achei qual opção eu faço isso. Estou usando o `Highcharts`. Segue a imagem

[image: screenshot do gráfico com totais sobre as barras]]

Segue o código:

```
Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: "grafico_investimento5",
            width: 900
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Gastos Planejados & reais por Pilar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories:  pilares
        },
       yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Gastos'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -30,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: "{series.name}: R$ {point.y:,.2f} "
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series:
            [{
                name: 'Valor Planejado',
                data: [
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Sustentabilidade"]["valor_planejado"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Capacitação"]["valor_planejado"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Campanhas"]["valor_planejado"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Influenciadores"]["valor_planejado"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Superação"]["valor_planejado"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Geração de Demanda"]["valor_planejado"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Ações fora da Cadeia"]["valor_planejado"],
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Valor Real',
                data: [
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Sustentabilidade"]["valor_real"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Capacitação"]["valor_real"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Campanhas"]["valor_real"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Influenciadores"]["valor_real"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Superação"]["valor_real"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Geração de Demanda"]["valor_real"],
                    dados["grafico_investimento5"]["pilar"]["Ações fora da Cadeia"]["valor_real"],
                ]
            }]
    });
    dados_grafico_investimento5 = chart3.getCSV();
```

Gostaria de tirar esses números de cima da barra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for pra tirar os números da parte de cima da barra, troque

```
stackLabels: {
   enabled: true,
   style: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
   }
}
```

por

```
stackLabels: {
   enabled: false
}
```

Se quiser tirar os números que aparecem nas seções individuais, basta fazer o mesmo trocando a parte dos `dataLabels` assim:

```
dataLabels: {
   enabled: false
}
```

Demo oficial do Highcharts no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/)**

Agora o **[mesmo demo sem os ítens em cima](http://jsfiddle.net/89acqt5k/)**, conforme explicado na resposta.

E agora, **[sem nenhum número](http://jsfiddle.net/wdc7afmg/)**, desativando os `dataLabels` com a mesma lógica.

Comment: Não mudou em nada, continua aparecendo

Comment: Pus 3 demos funcionais na resposta.

Comment: Era o `dataLabels`. O primeiro que você me passou era pra tirar os dados total. Mas valeu, ajudou ;)

Comment: Atualizei sua pergunta pra tirar a expressão "de cima", pra evitar problemas de interpretação, e complementei a resposta destacando as 2 partes em separado